# Finding averages across three tables in sql

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have created three tables

route

```
routeNo decimal
routeName varchar
```

//each route has multiple stops, each stop is store as a lat/lon

Stops:

```
routeNo decimal
stopNo decimal

latitude decimal
longitude decimal
```

and

//order has a route with stops

orderDelivery:

```
routeNo decimal
stopNo decimal
orderNo decimal
```

//each driver has been assigned a route and a vehicle

workday:

```
workday date
driver char(9)
route decimal 4,0
vehicle char(7)
```

I have to find out, on which days did the number of stops made by all drivers
outnumber the daily average of stops (made by all drivers)

I understand that i need to join the three tables in order to get all of the required info. and have coded to find each drivers most visited stop as i thought this would help to find where it is likely that they will exceed the average number of stops.

my code so far:

```
SELECT t1.driver, t2.stopNo, t1.maxStop
FROM
(
    SELECT t.driver, MAX(t.stopCount) AS maxStop
    FROM
    (
        SELECT w.driver, s.stopNo, COUNT(s.stopNo) AS stopCount
        FROM workday w INNER JOIN Stops s ON w.route = s.routeNo
        INNER JOIN orderDelivery od ON s.routeNo = od.routeNo AND s.stopNo =      od.stopNo
         GROUP BY w.driver, s.stopNo
    ) t
    GROUP BY t.driver
) t1
 INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT w.driver, s.stopNo, COUNT(s.stopNo) AS stopCount
    FROM workday w INNER JOIN Stops s ON w.route = s.routeNo
    INNER JOIN orderDelivery od ON s.routeNo = od.routeNo AND s.stopNo =      od.stopNo
  GROUP BY w.driver, s.stopNo
    ) t2
ON t1.driver = t2.driver AND t1.maxStop = t2.stopCount
```

Comment: Where do you record what a driver actually did (as opposed to what the were scheduled to do)?

Comment: @Strawberry I'm starting to think that may be what orderDelivery records.

Comment: I assume the driver carried out all assigned stops on the schedule, so I'm essentially trying to find the stops that exceed the average on the schedule

Comment: @HarAdams, after I realized that `stops` is a static table of locations I went back to that same assumption.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a stab:

```
select w.workday, count(*) as dailyCount
from
    workday w inner join
    stops s on s.routeNo = w.route inner join
    orderDelivery d on d.routeNo = s.routeNo and r.stopNo = s.routeNo
group by w.workday
having count(*) /* daily count */ > (
    select avg(dailyCount) /* average across all days for all drivers */
    from (
        select count(*) as dailyCount
        from
            workday w inner join
            stops s on s.routeNo = w.route inner join
            orderDelivery d on d.routeNo = s.routeNo and r.stopNo = s.routeNo
        group by w.workday
    ) dc
)
```